# listpicker for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, listpicker

**I am new to windows 8 phone application development.**

I want implement listpicker in my application. I have gone through few post and installed Nuget package. After installing, I straight a way went to XAML and added the below code

```
< toolkit:ListPicker Header="Default" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="defaultPicker" />
```

I am getting a blue zig-zag line underneath the code(Means there is some error). Can any one help me in implementingthe listpicker functionality. It will be so helpful if you can explain with sample code.

Comment: did you check the error tab in visual studio? Normally you should find there a description message of the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the namespace declaration of the WPtoolkit assembly.
In your XAML namespaces declaration you should have this line:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the namespace in the header

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solution:

- use mvvm pattern
  Create ViewModel.
  Create binding.

  private List _myList;

  public List MyList
  { 
      get { return _myList; }
      set
      {
          _myList= value;
          this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyList");
      }
  }

public YourViewModel(){
MyList = new List();
MyList.add("TOTO");
}

Bind your listPicker.

- use code behind

Set the name of your listPicker

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="myList" Header="Default" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="defaultPicker" />
```

In your constructor.

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
s.add("TOTO");
myList.itemSource = s;
```